# Smoothing N-gram language models with Zr = Nr / 0.5 (t - q); What to do with the final frequency? (q, r, and t are successive non-zero frequences)

Tags: nlp, statistics

Question about language modeling, I'm trying to implement a Katz back-off model.

Many PDFs mention the equation I'm asking about: `Zr = Nr / 0.5 (t - q)`

Here's one for example.

[https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b92b02053/print/good-turing-smoothing-without.pdf](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Eb92b02053/print/good-turing-smoothing-without.pdf)

> Following the work in Church and Gale [1991], we average with each
> non-zero Nr with the zero Nr’s that surround it: order the non-zero Nr
> by r, and let q, r, and t be successive indices of non-zero values. We
> replace Nr by Zr=Nr/0. 5 (t−q). In other words we estimate the
> expected Nr by the density of Nr for larger. For small r, there is no
> difference, because the length of the intervals is unity.

They use the following table as an example of the data.

```
+---------+----------+
|frequency|frequency |
|         |of        |
|         |frequency |
+---------+----------+
|r        |Nr        |
+---------+----------+
|1        |268       |
+---------+----------+
|2        |112       |
+---------+----------+
|3        |70        |
+---------+----------+
|4        |41        |
+---------+----------+
|5        |24        |
+---------+----------+
|6        |14        |
+---------+----------+
|7        |15        |
+---------+----------+
|400      |1         |
+---------+----------+
|1918     |1         |
+---------+----------+
```

I see that `Zr = Nr / 0.5 (t-q)` smoothing mentioned in a lot of places but I never see mentioned how the final `Nr` is dealt with. q, r, and t represent 3 successive elements in a list. Once you get to the last element of the list, when that last element is r, then there is no t. What do you do then? Is it just excluded with the effect being deemed negligible after things are smoothed and a linear regression model is fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found several code examples that have solutions, but no explanation to go along with them.

```
        for (j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
                {
                i = (j == 0 ? 0 : r[j - 1]);
                if (j == rows - 1)
                        k = (double) (2 * r[j] - i);
                else
                        k = (double) r[j + 1];
                Z[j] = 2 * n[j] / (k - i);
                log_r[j] = log(r[j]);
                log_Z[j] = log(Z[j]);
                }
```

The question refers to the frequencies as `q`, `r`, and `t`. The sample code there uses `i`, `j`, and `k`.

Basically, for the last `t` that would be an index out of bounds, use `2 * Nr - q`.